# Probability of selecting 2 numbers from 5 (from Programming Pearls, 2nd Edition)

Tags: algorithm, probability

In page 126, Section 12.2:

The algorithm considers the integers 0, 1, 2, ..., n-1 in order, and selects
each one by appropriate random test. By visiting the integers in order, we
guarantee that the output will be sorted.

To understand the selection criterion, let's consider the example that m=2
and n=5. We should select the first integer 0 with probability 2/5; a
program implements that by a statement like

```
if (bigrand() % 5) < 2
```

My question is, why the probability of selecting the first integer is 2/5, instead of 1/5? Shouldn't the probability be 1/5 to choose one number randomly from 5 numbers?

Really bewildered here. Hopefully, someone could provide some clarification here.

Thanks!

Comment: `bigrand() % 5` can give 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, and 2 of which (0 and 1) is less than 2.

Comment: What is the goal of the algorithm? Selecting M of N numbers with equal probability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't the probability be 1/5 to choose one number randomly from 5 numbers?

That's one way to design a sampling algorithm, but this one works differently. It considers each element in turn and decides whether that element is part of the sample. Here's the decision tree for m=2 and n=4 (with deterministic decisions suppressed).

```
                            take 0?
               _____yes_____       _____no_____
              /                                \
             /                                take 1?
          take 1?                         yes/       \no
        yes/   \no                          /         \
          /     \                        take 2?     {2,3}
       {0,1}   take 2?                 yes/   \no
             yes/   \no                  /     \
               /     \                {1,2}   {1,3}
            {0,2}   {0,3}
```

At the root, 3/6 descendant outcomes include 0, and 0 is taken with probability 2/4 = 1/2. If we take 0, then only 1/3 outcomes include 1. If we don't take 0, then 2/3 outcomes include 1. At each step, the probability for each decision is proportional to the number of outcomes in the corresponding subtree, ensuring a uniform random subset of size m.

Comment: This graph is really intuitive!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that you're picking an ordered pair.  Then there would be probability 1/5 that the first number is the first number in the pair, and likewise probability 1/5 that the first number would be the second number in the pair.  (It would never be both the first and second number in the pair.)

Therefore it has 2 chances out of 5 to be somewhere in an ordered pair.

Picking a random unordered pair is the same as picking an ordered pair and then forgetting the order.  Therefore it has 2 chances out of 5 to be in the unordered pair as well.